# A polynomial reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ but irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to construct a polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ but irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$.

So far I've constructed a polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 2$, which I just want to know how to check if it is reducible or irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. Also I would like some advice on how to construct a polynomial that would satisfy the conditions given if such a polynomial exists.

Comment: An irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ is either of degree $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Your polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (you constructed it using a factorisation over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: Note that any polynomial of the form $2p(x)$ is reducible over $\Bbb Z$ but not necessarily $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Jmath99, try $4X^3-8$ ?

Comment: You need a monic polynomial for applying Eisensteins criterion, @ClémentGuérin gave you a polynomial that contains the key under such construction

Comment: As per Gauss' Lemma and friends irreducibility of a polynomial over $\Bbb{Z}$ is equivalent to irreducibility over $\Bbb{Q}$ except for eventual constant factors (those may be irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ but are necessarily units in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$).

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if there is anything more basic than $2 x^2 - 4$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/579921)

Comment: @Nizar: Oh, I should have said: "What is $2 x^2 - 4$ ? "

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution,$f(x) = 4x^3 + 12x^2 + 12x + 12$. Could someone verify if this polynomial satisfies the given conditions? I know $f(x)$ is cubic so is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$, and irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's Criteria.